# the limit of the ratio of two $\Gamma(x)$ functions

Tags: special-functions, asymptotics, gamma-function

I am interested in the quantity
$$
a_{n} = \sqrt{n/2} \frac{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$$
(this is the geometric bias of the [non-central t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Moments_of_the_Noncentral_t-distribution) with $n$ *d.f.*) After some plotting, my *hunch* is that
$a_n \approx 1 + \frac{3}{4n} + \mathcal{O}\left(n^{-2}\right)$, as $n\to\infty$. Is there a known asymptotic result of this form? One may assume $n$ is an integer.

A little googling lead me to Feng Qi's [excellent survey](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jia/2010/493058/) of inequalities around ratios of $\Gamma$ functions of this form, but I cannot find an asymptotic expansion of this form.

Comment: You could also use the first few terms of the Stirling approximation to $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Craig: That's a good idea, and it's probably less mysterious than the DLMF formula I cite in my answer (it would be a bit more computationally intensive, however).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that $a_n = 1 + \frac{3}{4n} + O(n^{-2})$.  A reference is NIST's [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#iii), Equation 5.11.12, where they have
$$\frac{\Gamma(z+a)}{\Gamma(z+b)} \sim z^{a-b} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{G_k(a,b)}{z^k},$$
where 
$G_k(a,b) = \binom{a-b}{k} B^{(a-b+1)}_k(a),$
and $B_n^{(i)}(x)$ is a [generalized Bernoulli polynomial](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.16#i).

Your question has $z = n/2$, $a = -1/2$, $b = 0$.

If you take the DLMF formula out one more term, and using $G_0(a,b) =1$, $G_1(a,b) = \frac{1}{2} (a-b)(a+b-1)$, and $G_2(a,b) = \frac{1}{12} \binom{a-b}{2} (3(a+b-1)^2-(a-b+1))$, you get
$$a_n = 1 + \frac{3}{4n} + \frac{25}{32n^2} + O(n^{-3}).$$

---

*Added*: Believe it or not, [Wolfram Alpha can do this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BSqrt%5Bn/2%5D%20Gamma%5B%28n%20-%201%29/2%5D/Gamma%5Bn/2%5D,%20%7Bn,%20%5C%5BInfinity%5D,%205%7D%5D) for you as well.  For example, the link says that 
$$a_n = 1 + \frac{3}{4n} + \frac{25}{32n^2} + \frac{105}{128n^3} + \frac{1659}{2048 n^4} + \frac{6237}{8192 n^5} + O(n^{-11/2}).$$

Comment: I'm glad I didn't include my hunch for the $n^{-2}$ term, since it was quite a bit off!

Comment: thanks, again. A little more digging revealed that $a_n^{-1}$ is called '$c_4$' in the statistical process control literature (see _e.g._ http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/IQCC/html/c4.html). Mathworld has more info under the heading of 'standard deviation distribution' http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html